# I have purged the current kernel!

Tags: kernel, purge

Help - I have purged the current Kernel (linux-image-2.6.32-43-server) and cannot reinstall because the boot sector is full. How can I clear the boot sector to reinstall the kernel?

```
$ ls /boot
abi-2.6.32-44-server         initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic
abi-3.2.0-34-generic         initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic
abi-3.2.0-35-generic         initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic
abi-3.2.0-36-generic         lost+found
abi-3.2.0-37-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.2.0-38-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.2.0-39-generic         System.map-2.6.32-44-server
abi-3.2.0-40-generic         System.map-3.2.0-34-generic
abi-3.2.0-41-generic         System.map-3.2.0-35-generic
config-2.6.32-44-server      System.map-3.2.0-36-generic
config-3.2.0-34-generic      System.map-3.2.0-37-generic
config-3.2.0-35-generic      System.map-3.2.0-38-generic
config-3.2.0-36-generic      System.map-3.2.0-39-generic
config-3.2.0-37-generic      System.map-3.2.0-40-generic
config-3.2.0-38-generic      System.map-3.2.0-41-generic
config-3.2.0-39-generic      vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-44-server
config-3.2.0-40-generic      vmlinuz-2.6.32-44-server
config-3.2.0-41-generic      vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
initrd.img-2.6.32-44-server  vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic


$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-3*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-38-lowlatency' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-3*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-1615-armadaxp' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-3*'
[...CUT...]

    Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
    Package linux-image-3.2.0-40-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
    Package linux-image-3.2.0-41-lowlatency is not installed, so not removed
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

DPKG OUTPUT

```
$ dpkg-query -l linux-image*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  linux-image    <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-34.77   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-35.78   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-36.79   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-37.81   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-38.83   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-39.86   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-40.87   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-41.91   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-42.96   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
rc  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-43.97   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
ii  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-44.98   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86
un  linux-image-3. <none>         (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-34.53    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-35.55    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-36.57    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-37.58    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-38.61    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-39.62    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-40.64    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-41.66    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
in  linux-image-3. <none>         (no description available)
iU  linux-image-se 3.2.0.43.51    Linux kernel image on Server Equipment.
```

Comment: Boot sector full? You mean the boot partition? Post `df -h` please

Comment: /dev/sda1       228M  226M     0 100% /boot

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm in a bit of a panic. I also think my current kernel is 3.2.0-40-generic according to uname-r.

Comment: Ok, don't panic, you have a separate /boot partition, that is good thing. Just check how many kernels are installed and what versions. `ls /boot`

Comment: There are quite a few kernels, lets delete the older ones: `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-3*`

Comment: $ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.0.2.3*
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.0.27-1-ac100' for regex 'linux-image-3.0.2.3*'
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic  but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Not sure that worked?

Comment: You have mistyped the version number, it's `3.2.0-3*` you need to type it correctly.

Comment: Please see the edit on main post. The purge appears to have picked 3.2.0-4* stuff aswell - not that it worked??

Comment: No, it didn't select the `3.2.0-4*` stuff, but did it remove anything or that was all the output? What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Sorry the post seems to big here a are a few key lines. (many cuts!)

Comment: Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic-pae' for regex 'linux-image-3.2.0-3*'

Comment: Package linux-image-3.2.0-41-virtual is not installed, so not removed

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: What does `df -h` tell you now?

Comment: df -h still shows 100% full

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg-query -l linux-image*`

Comment: If you see the bottom of the main post - it thinks that the packages are not installed, so they are not removed?

Comment: dpkg-query in main post

Comment: Is this a server recently `dist-upgrade`-ed to 12.04?

Comment: Yes it should be 12.04 LTS - Server?

Comment: Seems like, did you just get this server to maintain? Run `cat /etc/issue` to find out, and let's roll an `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: $ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

Comment: The apt-get -f install fails - it tries to unpack 3.2.0.-43 generic and gets - "No space left on device" Disk full error

Comment: Then run `sudo apt-get -f remove`

Comment: Same again. Disk is Full.

Comment: Is it safe to physically delete some of the files?

Comment: Yes, delete some of the lower version files in `/boot`

Comment: You are welcome, now you can run `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-3* linux-image-2*`

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem.  The only thing that helped was manually removing enough files in /boot using

```
cd /boot
rm initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
```

for

```
apt-get -f install
```

to be able to complete normally.  Then use

```
 dpkg --list|grep linux-image
```

to identify linux images and remove enough of the oldes with e.g.

```
apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic-pae ...
```

Finally there might be some extra space to reclaim with

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
```

(I derived the above from other answers - this was was worked for me)

I believe that I've seen that Ubuntu now has some "clean up old kernels" functionality, but apparently it did not kick in here.

Comment: Aha! I deleted an older kernel physically and that allowed me to run apt-get -f install. I am now freeing up some of the older Kernels. Many thanks.